# Cleanness and Dirtiness

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

**Dirtiness:** the state of being dirty

> **Example:** 
>   - I don't mind a little bit of a mess - it's dirtiness I can't stand.

**Cleanness:** how something is clean

I need to know if using these two words in the further self-made sentence sounds idiomatic or not:

> - Nobody likes **dirtiness.**
> - Nobody dislikes **cleanness.**

I suspect whether native speakers in this sense say just:

> - Nobody likes **being dirty.**
> - Nobody dislikes **being clean**.

I would appreciate it if you let me know about them. If they're not natural, then what is the normal way to say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your examples seem correct *grammatically*. We tend to use "*cleanliness*" [more](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cleanness%2C%20cleanliness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccleanness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccleanliness%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccleanness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccleanliness%3B%2Cc0) than "cleanness", which doesn't even appear in some dictionaries. It seems like a mistake that has crept into common use, some people may accept it but others will not so my advice is do not use it.

The difference between "dirtiness" and "*being* dirty" is that the former can describe both the *quality* of being dirty *and* the *state* of being dirty either in oneself *or* in *other people*, whereas the latter is speaking exclusively about the state of oneself.

The sentences where you say "*nobody dislikes...*" do seem a little odd though. I'm not sure why you want to reverse the statements? They aren't incorrect, just unfamiliar sounding.

Your use of "mess" is a little ambiguous though. I think what you are trying to do is to highlight the difference between *cleanliness* (which involves getting rid of dirt, germs etc) and *tidiness* (which is specifically about order, things being in the right place etc). You could have a room which is *tidy*, in that everything is in its place and orderly, yet it could be covered in dust and therefore "dirty". The reason I say "mess" is ambiguous is that it can be used to describe untidiness, but it can also describe something that has become *dirty*.

As a general rule of thumb, use "cleanliness" and "dirtiness" when you are speaking about individuals, things, places or situations:

> Levels of cleanliness in the city are very good.
>   The dirtiness of the house was unbearable.

Use "being clean" and "being dirty" when speaking about a specific person or their environment, or the "quality" of being clean/dirty:

> John likes being clean.
>   Being dirty is not a nice feeling.

Comment: Thank you @Astralbee; but please provide me with some examples so that I could understand the differwnce between these five a little better; it's all over the map here for me. ;)

Comment: I need to know @Astralbee, where I can use "cleanness", "cleanliness", "dirtiness", "being clean" and "being dirty" and also where I cannot?

Comment: @A-friend I've added some examples. Don't use "cleanness" though, as many feel it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[You should use cleanliness instead of cleanness](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/cleanliness-and-cleanness). I can't think of another word where -liness and -ness are both used as suffixes though, so you've been unlucky with your choice of example. -ness is the most common as in *darkness or hardness*. -liness is usually used when -ness is to be added to a word that ends in -ly [like the words in this list](http://www.wordbyletter.com/suffixes/words_finishing_with_liness.php)

Your use of dirtiness is fine.